# C call from Smalltalk

Tags: c, smalltalk, visualworks

I'm trying to call [EnumServicesStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682637%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from within VisualWorks. For the first call I set the parameters to the required values to know how many bytes the returned information will require (pcbBytesNeeded).

Now I need to allocate memory for the lpServices buffer using malloc:, which expects the number of instances as an argument. How can I calculate this easily? Just dividing the pcbBytesNeeded by the size of of an LPENUM_SERVICE_STATUS struct makes my code crash when freeing the memory.

/Edit

I solved the crash when freeing the memory. (I accidently manipulated the variable holding the pointer). However, my question in the comment to Karsten is still valid. Why doesn't the size of ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS divide pcbBytesNeeded? Is this because of the LPTSTR lpServiceName and LPTSTR lpDisplayName members?

Answer (score 1):

you can send #sizeOf to the ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS structure, similar to the sizeof(ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS) in C.

Something like: 
numItems := pcbBytesNeeded / self ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS sizeOf.

please also make sure that you call the EnumServicesStatusW function, because EnumServicesStatus is a macro that actually points to EnumServicesStatusW.

Comment: That is what I'm doing now and makes it crash when freeing. numItems:= 22728 / 36 . That equals 631.333333333, which makes me think it's wrong :)

Comment: The documentation says that the number of services is returned in a pointer that's passed as argument. pcbBytesNeeded then holds the amount of memory required for the rest of the elements, because the buffer was too small. As the function computes the amount of memory and also answers the number of elements, it can very well be that it's not possible to compute the number of elements based on the required memory size.